angular v17 esbuild sass url resolve
I have different base-href-s per localizations (/de; /en; /nl ...).
In scss files I have background-image: url('assets/picture.png');, what cannot be resolved by builer. If I use path '/assets/...' the url resolver skips it, but then in looking for it in the https://mywebsite/assets/.... place and not with the path with basehref like https://mywebsite/de/assets/....
Do you have any idea how should it be handled properly?
Thanks in advance.
Tried to relative/absulate urls / options but no luck.
